# How to get stack trace from a Test::Unit::TestCase

Tags: ruby, testunit

I am testing some Ruby code and have a failing Test::Unit::TestCase. Unfortunately, the failure report only gives me the top error, not a full stack trace. Specifically, it says:

```
 1) Failure:
test_tp_make(TestScripts::TestTpMake) [test/test_scripts.rb:73]:
Exception raised:
<#<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>>.
```

The line number referenced (73) is the start of an assert_nothing_raised code block in my test case, which in turn starts another code block, which in turn calls in to a large library.

I have tried running the test with the --verbose flag, unfortunately this does not change the exception output. I tried consulting the Test::Unit documentation, but it does not seem to enumerate the available options (for example, there's nothing useful [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Options.html)). Searching the web and StackOverflow surfaced some answers on how to enable stack tracing in Rails, but this is non-Rails ruby code.

I could extract the failing code from the test and run it outside of Test::Unit, enabling me to see all the output. But it will be a pain to do this every time I have a failing test.

Does anyone know how to get Test::Unit to give me a full stack trace?

Comment: Are you running your test with `rake`?

Comment: Was this in Ruby 1.8, Ruby 1.9, or both?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking through the code of Test::Unit in Ruby 1.8, it seems all the errors go through the Test::Unit::Error object which filters the backtrace in its #long_display method.  There is no configuration and all runners will use the same filtered trace.

Brute force monkey patch to get the whole trace:  (I put this in my single test case file; perhaps you could put it in a test helper)

```
require 'test/unit/util/backtracefilter'

module Test::Unit::Util::BacktraceFilter
  def filter_backtrace(backtrace, prefix=nil)
    backtrace
  end
end
```

And monkey patch for Ruby 1.9 (which uses minitest)

```
def MiniTest.filter_backtrace(bt)
  bt
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this anywhere in you class to get full stack trace. I used it in my unit test case to debug my test class.

```
rescue => e

puts e.inspect

puts e.backtrace
```

Comment: Your solution is OK, but the problem is that it would negate the need for existence of Test::Unit - you suggest to manually trace all exceptions. The question was - how to fix Test::Unit to be useful again.